# How to thread-pool many single-threaded queues in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

Our application requires around 10,000 parallel work queues, each of which has the following characteristics:

1. Processing of queue items must be guaranteed to be in sequence. I.e. processing for one picked item must be completed before the next item gets picked from the same queue.
2. A queue gets a new entry every 3-5 minutes, so there's plenty of idling.
3. Different queues are fully independent (except that they're writing to the same database; no shared rows).

Naiv approach would be to have 10.000 dedicated single thread executors (from Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor). But from my understanding such an executor has a 1:1 relationship to a thread, resulting in 10,000 mostly idling threads.

At the moment, we're using Apache ActiveMQ but want to get rid of this piece of infrastructure.

Any smarter suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I would assume your database is the bottleneck. How many simultaneous operations can your database do efficiently? I would have about this number of threads or perhaps double.

Comment: Thanks Peter! With our load, we're far from actually challenging the database. It's more that because of the rather relaxed load, I'd like to take system complexity back to an appropriate level.

Comment: My general rule is; you can't get simpler than using just one thread.  Only add another thread if you a) you have tried to performance tune the code first, for CPU and allocations, b) know you need to, and c) you have tested that it actually helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you need to have one thread to service each queue.

A simple solution would be to have some reasonable number of threads that *poll* the queues:

```
final Queue<WorkItem>[] queues = ...;

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        for (Queue<WorkItem> queue : queues) {
            WorkItem workItem = queue.poll();
            if (workItem) {
                workItem.doWork();
            }
            Waitabit();
        }
    }
}

private static void Waitabit() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

In a more sophisticated solution, you could eliminate the need for polling by using some means, external to the queues, to notify the worker threads when there is work to be done.

---

But wait!  Why 10,000 parallel queues?  Why not one queue, where each queue item knows which one of 10,000 categories it belongs to?

Comment: Thanks @james-large! Your first approach required some handmade lock-notify logic - at least without polling. This is exactly the piece I'd like to avoid by using a standard library component. The second proposal seems feasible for our exepected load. It's just so counter-intuitive because it's exactly the definition of a bottleneck :-)

Comment: Hmm, I just recall the issue with "one queue to rule them all": Without additional logic, it won't guarantee sequential execution of related items.

Comment: @jmml, Ah!  I forgot the part where you said, "processing for one picked item must be completed before the next item is picked [_from the same queue_]."